# inverse relation need not to be a function.

Tags: functions, relations, inverse-function

Let $f:A \to B$. Let $f*$ be the inverse relation, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
f*= \{(y,x) \in B \times A \mid f(x)=y\}
\end{equation*}
Show by an example that $f*$ need not to be a function.

**Attempt:**

Let $A = B$ be the set of all real numbers greater or equal than $2$.

Define $f:A \to B$ by $f(x) = x^2+2x+3$ for all $x \in A$. Then, its inverse relation is $x = y^2 + 2y + 3$ for some $y \in B$.
Note that
\begin{align*}
x &= y^2 + 2y+3 \\
y^2 + 2y + (3-x) &= 0 \\
y &= \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(3-x)}}{2} \\
&= \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4x-8}}{2} \\
&= -1 \pm \sqrt{x-2}
\end{align*}
Hence, $f*(x) = -1 \pm \sqrt{x-2}$.

This has two values for a given value of $x$, so it is not a function; but it is still the inverse relation.

Is above true?

Comment: You should define $A$ and $B$

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary?

Comment: What if I take $A = B = \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: $f*(x)$ is not defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: The way you have it now, $f(A)\not\subset B$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner And then, how to define $A$ and $B$ correctly?

Comment: Using the simpler $f(x)=x^2$ for ease of arithmetic., in the case that $A=B=\Bbb Z$ you will have $f^*$ fails to be a function since $f^*(\{4\})=\{+2,-2\}$ so it fails to be well-defined as well as $f^*(\{5\})=\emptyset$ so it fails to be every-where defined.  That is to say, some numbers have multiple square roots and some numbers have no square roots.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, I will use it.

Comment: In the case that $A=B=\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x^2$ you again have $f^*$ fails to be a function since $f(\{-1\})=\emptyset$, the square root of $-1$ is not a real number.  In the case that $A=\Bbb R$ and $B=\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$, then $f^*$ *is* a function.  There is indeed one unique real non-negative square root of every non-negative number.

Comment: Now... this is an important reminder... a function's definition does matter very much what the domain and codomain are and these must be explicitly defined for the function.  When creating your own examples/counterexamples, you are generally free to choose whatever domains/codomains you wish, but such a selection must be explicitly made.  Depending on the choices made, what you are trying to show might or might not be true.

Comment: How about $f = \{(1,2), (1,3)\}$ ?

Comment: @SenZen what about it?  Your example of $f$ is not a function regardless what the domain and codomain are specified to be.  Your example of $f*$ might be a function in the event that the codomain of $f$ is specified to be $\{2,3\}$ and might not be a function if the codomain were anything else.